# Wordpress - how to add custom texts and links in social sharing?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add custom texts and links in Wordpress' sharing(by any plugin or anything) to social media sites, specially WhatsApp.
For example I am sharing a post with title and its link

**"This is a simple dummy title - https://example.com"**

Above link is default for any plugin.
But what I want is to add few more stuffs like below example :-

**"this is simple demo title - https://example.com / follow us on social media sites - twitter - (twitter link), instagram -(instagram link)"**

How can I achieve this in wordpress ? In other CMS, like MODX, I can make a custom chunk for each social share button. I don't know how to do this in wordpress.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your WordPress post template.

WhatsApp:

```
<a class="any-class" href="https://wa.me/?text=<?php the_title(); ?> View more: <?php echo get_permalink();?> and follow us on social media sites - twitter - https://twitter.com/user, instagram - https//instagram.com/user" target="_blank">Share on WhatsApp</a>
```

Twitter:

```
<a class="any-class" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php the_title(); ?> View more: <?php echo get_permalink();?>" target="_blank">Share on twitter</a>
```

Facebook:

```
<a class="any-class" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink();?>" target="_blank">Share on facebook</a>
```